# Script not loading when added dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jotform

I'm trying to dynamically add a script to my project using jQuery. The script is successfully added to the `head` tag but the content is not rendered in the `body` tag.

This is my code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "https://form.jotform.com/jsform/81003857231348";
        $("head").append(s);
    }
  </script>
```

However the script loads successfully if I add it directly:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://form.jotform.com/jsform/81003857231348"></script>`

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/98587/

Am I missing something?

Comment: Use [`getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript)

Comment: Where is the script in relation to your jquery declaration?

Comment: Remove ``type="text/javascript"``

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO I removed that and still not loading. I first add jquery  and then try to append this script

Comment: If your js file https://form.jotform.com/jsform/xxxxxxxx is not valid js file it will not load. it will give 404 i guess.

Comment: @BabaKhedkar I have a valid js file, but I can't make it public

Comment: If you have code is like mentioned above then it should load. provided that your condition if(window.location.href.indexOf('script-services') !== -1)  is satisfied.

Comment: @BabaKhedkar it doesn't load even if I remove that condition. I'm testing on jsfiddle and it only works if I add directly the script tag

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ktL8sr12/ I have just replaced your js file with jquery file. its loading properly.

Comment: I created a new jsfiddle with a basic example where you can reproduce the issue

Comment: It is working fine for me. I only removed your if check.

Comment: How do you want to make sure that script is loading ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra by checking if the content is rendered

Comment: @BabaKhedkar can you update your jsfiddle with the working script?

Comment: @Valip try this https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/98725/

Comment: @Valip  you have not added any HTML so it is not rendering anything

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra try just with <script type="text/javascript" src="https://form.jotform.com/jsform/81003857231348"></script> and you'll see that there will be a content rendered. This is what I'm trying to achieve ... to render the same content, but adding the script using jquery

Comment: oops. your script is loading but getting an error "Cannot read property 'attachEvent' of null" and that is the issue.

Comment: @Valip I have added the answer please make such changes in your js and then it will work, issue is in line **document.wirte(<yourHtmlString>)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution,

First of all you can not write anything to document from external loaded script,

*Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': 
It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened*

There are two ways to solve this.

**1).**

You are creating **Iframe**  as html content and writing into document as

```
document.write(htmlCode)
```

Above line creating issue for dynamic loading your content.

Instead of your code try something like below.

```
var htmlCode = document.createElement("iframe");
 htmlCode.setAttribute("title", title.replace(/[\\"']/g,'\\$&').replace(/&amp;/g,'&'));
 htmlCode.setAttribute("src","");
 htmlCode.setAttribute("allowtransparency","true");
 htmlCode.setAttribute("allow","geolocation; microphone; camera");
 htmlCode.setAttribute("allowfullscreen","true");
 htmlCode.setAttribute("name",this.formId);
 htmlCode.setAttribute("id",this.iframeDomId);

 document.body.appendChild(htmlCode);
```

And add following Js code in your html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var s = document.createElement("script");
   s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "https://form.jotform.com/jsform/81003857231348";
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
</script>
```

**2).**

instead of

```
document.write(htmlCode)
```

Try

```
document.body.innerHTML=htmlCode
```

Let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: title is not defined`

Comment: @Valip Instead of html content you have to replace this code to generate iframe, then it will work

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle with an example of how this should work? I'm not sure if I understand...

Comment: @Valip, look at this file https://github.com/alpesh-jikadra/Resources/blob/master/js/81003857231348.js, **see line number 7 to 20**

Comment: That works! But how did you generate this link https://rawgit.com/alpesh-jikadra/Resources/master/js/81003857231348.js?

Comment: It seems that it only works with the url you've added in the script

Comment: @Valip I have already told you that you need to make changes in your JS file as I made in file at line number 7 to 20 as above github link shows, please make that changes in your file and let me know whether it is working or not.

Comment: @Valip I have updated my answer with 2 options, Second option can be useful where minimal code change is required.

Comment: Sorry, I get it now. Thank you for helping with this!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
window.onload = function() {
   //your script declaration here
}
```

instead of `jquery ready()`

Comment: and use `document.head.appendChild(s);` try to exclude all the jQuery stuffs, and check in inspector if your script tag is in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can load and execute a script with jQuerys [getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/). It does not need to be in the DOM to get access on your elements.

```
$.getScript ("test.js", function (){

    alert ("Running test.js");

});
```